# Checking Python standard library function/method calls for compatibility with old Python versions

Tags: python, static-analysis, pylint

I have a set of scripts and utility modules that were written for a recent version of Python 3.  Now suddenly, I have a need to make sure that all this code works properly under an older version of Python 3.  I can't get the user to update to a more recent Python version -- that's not an option.  So I need to identify all the instances where I've used some functionality that was introduced since the old version they have installed, so I can remove it or develop workarounds.

Approach #1:  eyeball all the code and compare against documentation.  Not ideal when there's this much code to look at.

Approach #2:  create a virtual environment locally based on the old version in question using pyenv, run everything, see where it fails, and make fixes.  I'm doing this anyway, because backporting to the older Python will also mean going backwards in a number of needed third-party modules from PyPi, and I'll need to make sure that the suite still functions properly.  But I don't think it's a good way to identify all my version incompatibilities, because much of the code is only exercised based on particular characteristics of input data, and it'd be hard to make sure I exercise all the code (I don't yet have good unit tests that ensure every line will get executed).

Approach #3:  in my virtual environment based on the older version, I used pyenv to install the pylint module, then used this pylint module to check my code.  It ran; but it didn't identify issues with standard library calls.  For example, I know that several of my functions call subprocess.run() with the "check_output=" Boolean argument, which didn't become available until version 3.7.  I expected the 3.6 pylint run to spot this and yell at me; but it didn't.  Does pylint not check standard library calls against definitions?

Anyway, this is all I've thought of so far.  Any ideas gratefully appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: No, I don't think pylint does what you want. `pyright` or `mypy` may catch this, but it would be a mess if the library wasn't correctly annotated to begin with.

Comment: "I don't yet have good unit tests that ensure every line will get executed" `<--` this is really the correct solution: good unit tests combined with a coverage checker so that you know your code is being thoroughly exercised. If you have the option, I would consider prioritizing work on your test suite; once you have that in place identifying 2 vs 3 issues will pretty much happen by virtue of running the tests.

Comment: @larsks according to the first paragraph, it's old 3 vs. new 3, not 2 vs. 3.

Comment: Eh, same comment, regardless of versions.

Comment: Thanks all!  While I agree that effective unit tests are necessary, and would solve this problem, I have to turn this around faster than the time it'd take to implement them.  We're giving mypy a try at present -- I hadn't been familiar with it before now (I'm much more of a physicist than I am a Python programmer, alas).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use pylint to check 3.6 code the most effective way is to use a 3.6 interpreter and environment and then run pylint in it. If you want to use the latest pylint version, you can use the [`py-version` option](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/configuration/all-options.html#py-version) using 3.6 but this is probably going to catch less issue because pylint will not check what you would have in python 3.6, only some known "hard coded" issue in python 3.6 (like for example f-strings for python 3.5, not missing args in subprocess.run).

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, the real issue is that you do not have a proper test suite, so the question is how can you get one cheaply.

Adding unit test can be time consuming. Before doing that, you can add actual end-to-end tests (which will take some computational time and longer feedback time, but that will be easier to implement), by simply running the program with the current version of python that it is working with and storing the results and then adding a test to show you reproduce the same results.

This kind of test is usually expensive to maintain (as each time you are updating the behavior, you have to update the results). However, there are a safeguard against regression, and allow you to perform some heavy refactoring on legacy code in order to move to a more testable structure.

In your case, these end-to-end test will allow you to test against several versions of python the actual application (not only parts of it).

Once you have a better test suite, you can them decide if this heavy end-to-end tests are worth keeping based on the maintenance burden of the test suite (let's not forget that the test suite should not slow you down in your development, so if it is the bottleneck, that means you should rethink your testing)

What will take time is to generate good input data to your end-to-end tests, to help you with that, you should use some coverage tool (you might even spot unreachable code thanks to that). If there are part of your code that you don't manage to reach, I would not bother at first about it, as it means it will be unlikely to be reached by your client (and if it is the case and it fails at your client, be sure to have proper logging implemented to be able to add the test case to your test suite)

Comment: True, but also 100 times as costly as launching a static analysis tool with the right options.